# how to add <a> HTML tag or URL in object array in .ejs

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I am new to creating array object , and I dont know how to add link in `<a>` tag in an array

object code:

```js
powerUpList: [ 
  {
      id:1,
      name:'Stack Export',
      description:'Export your complete stack back in an excel sheet. ',
      url: "https://help.stackby.com/article/145-export-stack-in-excel",
      category:'Data Recovery',
      status:0,
    },
    {
      id:2,
      name:'Microsoft Excel Importer',
      description:'Import an excel file to create a new stack or import it to a table. ',
      url: "https://help.stackby.com/article/146-excel-importer",
      category:'Import',
      status:0,
    },
    {
      id:3,
      name:'Append CSV file in an existing table',
      description:'Import a CSV file into an existing table and map the columns to take the form of your table. ',
      url: "https://help.stackby.com/article/144-import-data-in-an-existing-table",
      category:'Data Transformation',
      status:0,
    },
],

powerUpCategoryList: [
  'Data Recovery',
  'Import',
  'Data Transformation',
  'Sharing',
  'Automation',
  'Apps',
],
```

this is my JS object code

and this is actual code in .ejs where all instance perform , and the accordian does not close ,

powerup.ejs

```html
<div class="col-md-9" id="root">
  <div role="tablist" id="accordion-1">
    <%for (var i = 0; i < powerUpList.length; i++) { %>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" role="tab">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="accordion-1 .item-<%= i+1 %>" href="div#accordion-1 .item-<%= i+1 %>"><%= powerUpList[i].name%></a>

          <%if (powerUpList[i].status == 0) { %>
              <a class="live-lable status-live" >
                Live 
              </a>
            <%}else if(powerUpList[i].status == 1){-%>
              <a class="live-lable status-comingsoon" >
                Coming soon 
              </a> 
            <%}else if(powerUpList[i].status == 2){-%>
              <a class="live-lable status-beta" >
                In-Beta 
              </a> 
            <%}-%>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse show item-<%= i+1 %>" role="tabpanel" data-parent="#accordion-1">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text" ><%= powerUpList[i].description%></p>
               --------- HERE I WAnt to show **URL** as learn more
              <a href="<%- powerUpList[i].url%>" target="_blank">Learn more..</a> 
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <%}-%>
  </div>
</div>
```

here , I want to show in **url: "https://help.stackby.com/article/145-export-stack-in-excel",**  in as download link , and open new window , but i don't know how to add in `<a>` tag in file

Comment: It is very unclear what you want.  You normally do not store HTML in an object. What is not working for you when you code `<a href="<%- powerUpList[i].url%>"` ?

Comment: @mplungjan  i want to show url object in <a> learn more </a>

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can do

```html
<a href="<%- powerUpList[i].url %>">learn more</a>
```